# Bash "strict" mode and arrow (>) operator

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Here's the contents of `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

# bar is an unexisting command
bar > test
```

When I invoke `./myscript.sh` I get the following error message (which is expected),

```
./myscript.sh: line 5: bar: command not found
```

but an empty `test` file is created:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 spg  staff     0B 23 Feb 16:32 test
```

I thought that by activating "strict" mode (using the combination of `set -euo pipefail`), the failure to find the `bar` command would stop the script execution at this point, and not proceed to create the empty `test` file.

I would like to know how I could prevent the creation of the `test` file if the expression to the left of the `>` operator (in this case, `bar`) fails.

Comment: BTW, unlike perl's strict mode, whether `set -eu` is actually a good idea is... a very contentious and ongoing debate. See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (describing a few of the unintended consequences of `set -e`) and [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112) (describing some of the unintended consequences of `set -u`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy these are very interesting articles, thanks for sharing

Comment: Serious error handling in Bash requires (1) trapping errors instead of using `set -e` and (2) creating a way to handle why I call "exceptions" at each level in the call hierarchy.  Done right, it allows your script to tell the difference between an explicitly handled failure scenario and a bug.  It ends up looking like a try/catch mechanism.  It requires more shell code (and more discipline) than most people are willing to invest, but it is doable, reusable, and once achieved, you are free from the tyranny of logical operators eating return codes resulting from bugs inside functions.

Comment: My comment was a bit broad, let me narrow it down to three basic elements I think are important.  (1) explicitly handle any non-zero return code that is part of the normal execution of your script.  (2) To perform this handling, collect return codes outside `||` and `&&` constructs (other than `some_command || return_code=$?`), and use logical operators only for tests (e.g. `if` statements, loop conditions).  (3) use `trap` to catch all remaining non-zero return codes, which are bugs, and should result in your script exiting.  Always use `set -u`, but not `set -e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirection is done before the process is invoked so that it's stdout (in this case) can be connected to the file.  That's why `test` is created even though `bar` doesn't exist.  It doesn't know that invoking the command will fail when it sets up the redirection.

I don't think there's a straightforward way to avoid creating the file while using redirection.  You could try to test whether `bar` would succeed first by doing, say,

```
if command -v bar; then
    bar > test
else
    exit 1 # or whatever you want since the command would have failed
fi
```

Comment: I'd actually invert this: `if ! command -v bar; then exit 1; fi` and put it at the beginning of the script. Once you've verified that any critical commands are present, the remainder of the script can be written with the knowledge that any errors won't be due to missing commands.

Comment: A more generic approach is run the command redirecting to a temp file, then if successful `mv` it to the desired file.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin one cautionary note about that approach though is that it won't preserve permissions and ownership.  Redirecting into the file will leave its existing permissions intact, while creating a new file and moving it over the old name will not